# c# linq how to check for null values in the same column that i need to be not null

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this query in linq

```
var finalResults = (from r in results.AsEnumerable()
                   where DateTime.Now.Subtract(r.Field<DateTime>("SentOn")).Minutes > 7
                   select r
                   ).ToList();
```

sometimes the `SentOn` column could be null and I want to ignore these cases. how can I remove these null cases ?

if it is required we can do a staging (another) table that has just the not null values and i can continue

the table is `results` so can I have another table, lets say `results2` that doesn't have the null values or `SentOn` ?

Comment: Try this: Where r.Field<DateTime?>("SentOn").HasValue && your other conditions

Comment: @Kram i already know about `?` but the problem is i couldn't add two conditions together

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: If your issues is you don't know how to have two conditions then you should really make that clear in your question. At the moment it reads that you don't know how to check if the value is null.

Comment: @Chris it seems not just me who doesnt' know, until now, none of the 5 unswers have worked

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: The problem is that people are usually not in a position to actually run the code they are suggesting to you so sometimes you get non-fucntional code. In this case many answerers forgot that `DateTime` is a value type and thus can never be null and this causes problems if your underlying value is null (in that it can't assign the value) and means it is pointless to compare the result to null. Just goes to show even experienced programmers have problems.

Comment: My point though was that if you already knew about nullable types (ie the `?`) and your problem was just in combining the null check with your existing check then you should have made that more clear. Then people's answers would have focused on doing `a && b` rather than making mistakes with `DateTime` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the field `SentOn` can be `null`, you have to return `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime`.

Try:

```
var finalResults = (from r in results.AsEnumerable()
                   where r.Field<DateTime?>("SentOn") != null &&
                         DateTime.Now.Subtract(r.Field<DateTime>("SentOn")).Minutes > 7
                   select r
                   ).ToList();
```

Alternatively, as pointed out in the comment, you can use [`DataRow.IsNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fwatee0(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var finalResults = (from r in results.AsEnumerable()
                   where !r.IsNull("SentOn") &&
                         DateTime.Now.Subtract(r.Field<DateTime>("SentOn")).Minutes > 7
                   select r
                   ).ToList();
```

Comment: Better to just use the `IsNull` method in my view rather than getting the field out just for a null check. It will save allocation of new object and is more readable (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

Just add the test in your `WHERE` clause:

```
var finalResults = (from r in results.AsEnumerable()
               where !r.IsNull("SentOn") 
                     && DateTime.Now.Subtract(
                           r.Field<DateTime>("SentOn")).Minutes > 7
               select r
               ).ToList();
```

Comment: Does `r.Field<DateTime>(...)` not return a `DateTime` type which can never be null?

Comment: i got this error `Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type.` in your code

Comment: if this line r.Field<DateTime>("SentOn") return null that you'll have NullReference exception in your DateTime.Subtract method

Comment: @Fabjan: That line will always return a `DateTime` so can never be null though as Marco has already said that line can thrown an exception if the underlying value is null. Also given there is a null check before it wouldn't throw a null reference exception anyway.

Comment: I modified my answer. it uses `DateTime?` and `HasValue` now.

Comment: there was a guy before you give me the correct ansewr, sorry, +1 for the efforts

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`IsNull` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if the value is null first. This can be done as follows:

```
var finalResults = (from r in results.AsEnumerable()
                   where !r.IsNull("SentOn") &&
DateTime.Now.Subtract(r.Field<DateTime>("SentOn")).Minutes > 7
                   select r
                   ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this in your .Where method with just 'if' statement:

```
var finalResults = results.AsEnumerable().Where(r =>
{
   if(r.Field<DateTime?>("SentOn") == null) return false;
   return DateTime.Now.Subtract(r.Field<DateTime?>("SentOn")).Minutes > 7;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Accidentally added additional ')' sign in 'if' clause.  I've updated my answer

Comment: afterr your update, i got `Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type.` on the `if ` line

Comment: I don't get it. Your Field<DateTime>("SentOn") method always returns DateTime ? Then why do you want to check if its null or not ? And if it can be null then why are you getting this error ? It's probably something wrong with the method itself. It should return nullable DateTime

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<DateTime?>("SentOn") != null && DateTime.Now.Subtract(r.Field<DateTime>("SentOn")).Minutes > 7);
```

Comment: i got syntax error, on the `where` line, it seems you mssed `)` ??

Comment: after update, i got `: Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type.` on this part of your code `r.Field<DateTime>("SentOn") != null && DateTime.Now.Subtract(r.Field<DateTime>("SentOn")).Minutes > 7`

Comment: @MairajAhmad: Its your answer that is wrong. Shouldn't you be making it nullable in your answer? At the moment your answer will fail if the field is null (as marco said) and if its not null you are comparing a value type to null which is a pointless check.

Comment: @Chris Yes i added in comments will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A null check should suffice.

```
var finalResults = results.AsEnumerable().Select(r => !r.IsNull(("SentOn"))
            && DateTime.Now.Subtract(r.Field<DateTime>("SentOn")).Minutes > 7)
```

You could create an Extension Method if this is a repeated pattern.